# Change the language locale for chrome.app?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, google-chrome-app, multilingual, nw.js

My question, I want to change Target in Shortcut with JavaScript

Example
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xxx\something.exe

become

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xxx\something.exe --lang=zh

Reason:

I want to switch language for chrome app  (zh means chinese)

I use nw.js which has locale en folder message.json and zh folder message.json

my app using google i18n. The problem is chrome.i18.getMessage is very easy to use but there is no method like chrome.i18n.setlocale(zh) (setting your language json file as chinese)

Thus, this gives me a huge difficulty in term of language switcher

there is a way is you create two short cut
one short cut normal
another shortcut change target as
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\xxx\something.exe --lang=zh

Then, when you open this short cut, your language will be the message.json in zh folder, which is chinese

what I want

i want there is a drop down list. when user select chinese, it closes app and open another short cut

or

one short cut. when the user selects Chinese it becomes Chinese. when the user selects English it becomes English

switch language is easy if you write your own i18n

but my boss asks me using chrome.i18n so it is very hard for me to switch locales

the only way to change the locale according google is

Change the shortcut's properties so that the Target field specifies the language.
--lang and --user-data-dir flags. The target should look something like this:

path_to_chrome.exe --lang=locale --user-data-dir=c:\locale_profile_dir

what i can do to write a javascript to change the locale for chrome.app???

Comment: Please make your post more concise and less confusing,

Comment: This question was asked many times. The answer is still the same: the only solution is to switch to another localization library. You can find it using a search site like google.com

Comment: @WoxxOm, thanks very much. This question actually asked by me half a year ago and answered by you. and then i use your suggestion to another localization library. It works. but the sad story is i use nw.js 0.31 version to do that.. some of my customer use nw.js 0.24. my localization javascript plugin wrote by my self works on 0.31 but not on 0.24.....really don 't know why...i am a lost sheep. lose my own way. but thanks you wOxxOm, you always help people out of trouble